# How can I combine these codes in powershell?

Tags: powershell, netstat

```
        (Get-NetUDPEndpoint |
        Select-Object   LocalPort, OwningProcess
    ) + (Get-NetTCPConnection |
        Select-Object  LocalPort, OwningProcess
    ) |
        Sort-Object LocalPort, LocalAddress
```

---

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service | Select-Object Name, ProcessId
```

> I want to combine the above two codes and output like below

```
 Name                    LocalPort OwningProcess       
 application name        135          1148
 application name        135          1148
 application name        137             4
 application name        138             4
 application name        138          2084
 application name        139             4
 application name        445             4
 application name        500          3932
 application name        500          3932
```

> Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by building two dictionaries that map process IDs to processes and services:

```
$processes = @{}
Get-Process |ForEach-Object { $processes[$_.Id] = $_ }

$services = @{}
Get-CimInstance Win32_Service |ForEach-Object {
  # multiple services might share a process host, make sure we always store or update an array
  if(-not $services.ContainsKey($_.ProcessId)){
    $services[$_.ProcessId] = @( $_ )
  } else {
    $services[$_.ProcessId] += $_
  }
}
```

Now that we have a convenient mapping of process IDs to process and service entities, we can use [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2) to resolve the names based on the PID:

```
@(
  Get-NetUDPEndpoint
  Get-NetTCPConnection
) |Select @{Name='Process';Expression={ $processes[[int]$_.OwningProcess].Name }},@{Name='Services';Expression={ $services[$_.OwningProcess].Name }},LocalPort,OwningProcess
```